# How to programmably get the metadata of all packages available from AUR in ArchLinux?

Tags: python, archlinux

How to programmably get the metadata of all packages available from AUR in ArchLinux, including those not installed locally? Preferably in Python.

I have tried [AurJson](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AurJson), a set of APIs for accessing package metadata, but a minimum length of search keywords has to be provided to query package metadata.

Comment: What have you tried or researched so far?

Comment: @KlausD. See my edits

Comment: Isn't that open source? You could simply look at the code then.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It is a set of API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an interesting question!

#### AUR packages

You can get the list of all AUR packages from https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.gz .

You could then use the AurJson interface's `info` request and batch in a number (not sure what's the maximum per request) of packages:

https://aur.archlinux.org/rpc.php/rpc/?v=5&type=info&arg[]=criu&arg[]=criu&arg[]=criu&arg[]=criu&arg[]=criu&arg[]=criu&arg[]=criu&arg[]=criu

Be sure to play nice and throttle your requests! Something like this would get you started...

```
import requests

packages = requests.get('https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.gz').text.splitlines()
batch_size = 50
package_infos = {}

while packages:
    batch, packages = packages[:batch_size], packages[batch_size:]
    for result in requests.get(
        'https://aur.archlinux.org/rpc.php/rpc/',
        params={'v': 5, 'type': 'info', 'arg[]': batch},
    ).json()['results']:
        package_infos[result['Name']] = result
    break  # Replace this with throttling code :)

print(package_infos)
```

results in

```
{'adwaita-dark-darose': {'Depends': ['gnome-themes-standard'],
                         'Description': 'Adwaita theme hacked to use my custom '
                                        'color scheme. (Dark blues instead of '
                                        'greys.)',
                         'FirstSubmitted': 1493136022,
                         'ID': 464990,
                         'Keywords': [],
                         'LastModified': 1511841278,
                         'License': ['GPL'],
                         'Maintainer': 'darose',
                         'MakeDepends': ['glib2', 'gtk3'],
                         'Name': 'adwaita-dark-darose',
                         'NumVotes': 3,
                         'OutOfDate': None,
                         'PackageBase': 'adwaita-dark-darose',
                         'PackageBaseID': 121780,
                         'Popularity': 0.024409,
                         'URL': 'none',
                         'URLPath': '/cgit/aur.git/snapshot/adwaita-dark-darose.tar.gz',
                         'Version': '3.22.3-10'},
 'atari-adventure': {'Depends': ['stella'],
                     'Description': 'The original Adventure game for the old '
                                    'Atari 2600 game console',
                     'FirstSubmitted': 1247592088,
                     'ID': 214107,
                     'Keywords': [],
                     'LastModified': 1437534447,
                     'License': ['unknown'],
                     'Maintainer': 'darose',
                     'Name': 'atari-adventure',
                     'NumVotes': 2,
                     'OutOfDate': None,
                     'PackageBase': 'atari-adventure',
                     'PackageBaseID': 28288,
                     'Popularity': 0,
                     'URL': 'http://www.atariage.com/software_page.html?SoftwareID=802',
                     'URLPath': '/cgit/aur.git/snapshot/atari-adventure.tar.gz',
                     'Version': '1.0-3'},
....
```

#### Arch packages

(I misunderstood the original question, but here's the original answer.)

You can look at the Arch database files, which are, [according to the Arch Linux wiki, tar.gz files](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pacman#Database_structure), using the `tarfile` library in Python.

So assuming you've downloaded core.db/community.db/extra.db from a mirror (e.g. https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/archlinux/core/os/x86_64/core.db / https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/archlinux/community/os/x86_64/community.db / https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/archlinux/extra/os/x86_64/extra.db but please use another mirror closer to you), you can read them e.g. (Python 3)

```
import tarfile
tf = tarfile.open('core.db', 'r:gz')
for member in tf.getmembers():
    if member.name.endswith('/desc'):
        with tf.extractfile(member) as fp:
            print(fp.read().decode())
            print('-' * 40)
```

which prints out the description files in their native format, e.g.

```
%FILENAME%
archlinux-keyring-20180404-1-any.pkg.tar.xz

%NAME%
archlinux-keyring

%VERSION%
20180404-1

%DESC%
Arch Linux PGP keyring

%CSIZE%
684236

%ISIZE%
948224

%MD5SUM%
9ba27bf598d60f2ea6320339289a2401

%SHA256SUM%
6f0f2f8d72742da18b61b7e4a1900d419c718b6d9dcad804763b80a12cc9abaf

%PGPSIG%
iQEzBAABCAAdFiEE82kWh9hnuBtRzgfZu+Q3cUhzKKkFAlrEfLMACgkQu+Q3cUhzKKmE7ggAgNjBAz6FkFqy2+Q0Rfzt0ZibYT/KW6ibQoKgpxDQNkzcl/1ZVzS4rkZRjHkBJd8fKI2n6NtiijwiQBPBsTI8t4+nVD19C4zZbDHzTdABm4EaDdJg+ya635Df8xMqt6GNzxV5DmABioSww2ebY9EuSwl3yvMNTQUI8hAjWPfOirDRZDic9DEYvhPabUn9NlLzShQeDIZP/R0ejDCfBIcu2NMX+NSUg41w0+LGrLNpqdnI+ej0n3X6NDkvCZwvvC3DPCWs1PAhFS5yC5dve4pDBjf8fLuJBPbRQJx6Se0K0CCoeUVA2V4ld2HLXor1aLG0bijF2QhMLzHmW4XxWbpWLA==

%URL%
https://projects.archlinux.org/archlinux-keyring.git/

%LICENSE%
GPL

%ARCH%
any

%BUILDDATE%
1522826386

%PACKAGER%
Bartłomiej Piotrowski <bpiotrowski@archlinux.org>
```

EDIT: you can also parse the database files into dicts with something like

```
def read_aur_db_entry(fp):
    db_entry = collections.defaultdict(str)
    key = None
    for line in fp.readlines():
        if line.startswith(b'%') and line.endswith(b'%\n'):
            key = line[1:-2].decode()
            continue
        db_entry[key] += line.decode()
    return {key: value.strip() for (key, value) in db_entry.items()}
```

so you get

```
{'ARCH': 'any',
 'BUILDDATE': '1522826386',
 'CSIZE': '684236',
 'DESC': 'Arch Linux PGP keyring',
 'FILENAME': 'archlinux-keyring-20180404-1-any.pkg.tar.xz',
 'ISIZE': '948224',
 'LICENSE': 'GPL',
 'MD5SUM': '9ba27bf598d60f2ea6320339289a2401',
 'NAME': 'archlinux-keyring',
 'PACKAGER': 'Bartłomiej Piotrowski <bpiotrowski@archlinux.org>',
 'PGPSIG': 'iQEzBAABCAAdFiEE82kWh9hnuBtRzgfZu+Q3cUhzKKkFAlrEfLMACgkQu+Q3cUhzKKmE7ggAgNjBAz6FkFqy2+Q0Rfzt0ZibYT/KW6ibQoKgpxDQNkzcl/1ZVzS4rkZRjHkBJd8fKI2n6NtiijwiQBPBsTI8t4+nVD19C4zZbDHzTdABm4EaDdJg+ya635Df8xMqt6GNzxV5DmABioSww2ebY9EuSwl3yvMNTQUI8hAjWPfOirDRZDic9DEYvhPabUn9NlLzShQeDIZP/R0ejDCfBIcu2NMX+NSUg41w0+LGrLNpqdnI+ej0n3X6NDkvCZwvvC3DPCWs1PAhFS5yC5dve4pDBjf8fLuJBPbRQJx6Se0K0CCoeUVA2V4ld2HLXor1aLG0bijF2QhMLzHmW4XxWbpWLA==',
 'SHA256SUM': '6f0f2f8d72742da18b61b7e4a1900d419c718b6d9dcad804763b80a12cc9abaf',
 'URL': 'https://projects.archlinux.org/archlinux-keyring.git/',
 'VERSION': '20180404-1'}
```

Comment: Thanks! But AUR does not seem to use the same database file as the official packages, does it?

Comment: @xuhdev I added an additional answer for AUR :)

Comment: Thanks :) Perhaps `type=name` is enough? The results should be more unique and saves workload for the server.

Comment: `type=name` says "Incorrect request type specified.". The package info request is documented on the AurJson page though. :)

Comment: Opps, you are right. Thanks for the great answer :)

Answer (score -1):

I grabbed the AUR json db and used some tricky regex to format it into a text file

```
zcat <(curl  https://aur.archlinux.org/packages-meta-ext-v1.json.gz) | jq --compact-output '.[] | {Name, Version, Description, Keywords, PackageBase, URL, Popularity, OutOfDate, Maintainer, FirstSubmitted, LastModified, Depends, MakeDepends, License}' | perl -pe 's/^\{\"|\"?,"(?![^:]+\])/\n/g' | perl -pe 's/\\(?=")|\"(?=:)|:\K\[?\"\[?\"?|\"?\]\}?$//gm' | perl -pe 's/\",\" ?/ /gm' | perl -pe 's/^([^:]+)(:)(.*)$/$1                    $2 $3/gm' | perl -pe 's/^.{16}\K +//gm' | perl -0777 -pe 's/\n+(?=Name)/\n\n\nRepository      : AUR\n/gm' >packages-meta-ext-v1.json.extracted.txt
```

```
wc -l < packages-meta-ext-v1.json.extracted.txt
```

1341912

```
cat packages-meta-ext-v1.json.extracted.txt

Name            : 010editor
Version         : 12.0.1-1
Description     : Professional text and hex editing with Binary Templates technology
Keywords        : 010 binary hex sweetscape
PackageBase     : 010editor
URL             : https://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/
Popularity      : 0.003998
OutOfDate       : null
Maintainer      : Zrax
FirstSubmitted  : 1477968580
LastModified    : 1634742336
Depends         : libpng
MakeDepends     : fakechroot
License         : custom


Name            : 04b_21
Version         : 1-2
Description     : Symbol font from urbanfonts.com
Keywords        : null
PackageBase     : 04b_21
URL             : http://www.urbanfonts.com/fonts/04b_21.htm
Popularity      : 0
OutOfDate       : null
Maintainer      : Dragonlord
FirstSubmitted  : 1223994058
LastModified    : 1435513114
Depends         : fontconfig xorg-font-utils
MakeDepends     : null
License         : custom
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).